# How to use the Circular Output of the (still in alpha) Picamera 2 Python Library?

Tags: python, h.264, raspberry-pi4, picamera

**Using a Raspberry Pi, I would like to create a python script, which continuously records to a buffer, and then, when a signal is received (say the user types something into the terminal), the buffer is saved, and the previous frames are available to view.**

Using the [Picamera library](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/), this can be achieved using `picamera.PiCameraCircularIO()` and `stream.copy_to(file.h264)` to achieve this.

However, Picamera does not work on Bullseye OS. There is a new Python library, called [Picamera2](https://github.com/raspberrypi/picamera2), which I believe is in development by the RPi team.

From the [documentation](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/camera/picamera2-manual-draft.pdf) (section 7.2.3), it should be possible. The included example records a clip with 0 frames however, as `output.stop()` is run immediately after `output.start()`. To rectify this I added `time.sleep(5)` between those lines of code.

I have found that if the time between `picam2.start_recording(encoder, output)` and `output.start()` exceeds the buffersize (default 150 frames) then the output file has some issues with it - VLC does not play the file, MP4Box does not accept the file, but the file still has a size in the order of MiBs. I do not know much about video files, but I suspect the output file loses some key information when the old frames are rewritten by the new ones.

Here is my code:

```
from picamera2.encoders import H264Encoder
from picamera2.outputs import CircularOutput
from picamera2 import Picamera2
import time
import sys
picam2 = Picamera2()
picam2.configure(picam2.create_video_configuration())
encoder = H264Encoder()
output = CircularOutput(buffersize = 150)
picam2.start_recording(encoder, output)
t = input()
# Now when it's time to start recording the output, including the previous 5 seconds:
output.fileoutput = "file.h264"
output.start()
time.sleep(5)
# And later it can be stopped with:
output.stop()
```

*N.B.* This question may be better targeted towards the developers on GitHub. However I was not sure whether this was an Issue or a Discussion, so I have asked it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this w/out using input.

```
import sys
import time

from picamera2 import Picamera2
from picamera2.encoders import H264Encoder
from picamera2.outputs import CircularOutput

picam2 = Picamera2()
fps = 30
dur = 5
micro = int((1 / fps) * 1000000)
vconfig = picam2.create_video_configuration()
vconfig['controls']['FrameDurationLimits'] = (micro, micro)
picam2.configure(vconfig)
encoder = H264Encoder()
output = CircularOutput(buffersize=int(fps * (dur + 0.2)), outputtofile=False)
output.fileoutput = "file.h264"
picam2.start_recording(encoder, output)
time.sleep(dur)
output.stop()
```